# Creating a scope based off of a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, relationship

I'm using Rails 3.0.4 and Ruby 1.9.2

I'm trying to create a scope called role which takes a role string and returns all of the `User` records that have `role` as one of their roles.

The problem is `User` and `Role` have a HABTM relationship, and I don't really know how to access this information in a regular `User.where()` statement.

This is what I'm thinking:

```
scope :role, lamda {|role| where {|user| user.role? role} }
```

(role? is a method I wrote that just checks if a user belongs to that role)

Is there a way to pass the user object like that from where?  Or something that accomplishes the same thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Is role a separate model, or it is just a field inside of Users table?

Comment: It is a separate model with a Has and belongs to Many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If role is just a field in user model:

```
scope :with_role, lamda{|role_name| where(:role => role_name) }
User.with_role "Member"
```

If role is a separate model and `User belongs_to :role`. Also Role has got title field:

```
scope :with_role, lamda{|role_name| includes(:role).where(:roles => {:title => role_name}) }
User.with_role "Member" # the same usage
```

**UPD 1**

If `User has_many :roles` you should use User model method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles

  def self.with_role(role_name)
    Role.where(:name => role_name).first.users # hope title is validated uniq
  end
end
```

=> User.with_role("Member")

or using scope:

```
scope :with_role, lambda{ |role| joins(:roles).where(:roles => {:name => role}) }
```

Comment: and what argument are you passing? Role.title? Role.name?